# Single PHP form with 2 (edit and delete) buttons

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

I am trying to set up a form with 2 buttons - "DELETE" which runs on the page delete.php and "EDIT" which runs on edit.php.

So I need a different action depending on which button they have clicked...

Here's my code.

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("test", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable");

// Need to change the action depending on what button is clicked
echo "<form name='wer' id='wer' action='delete.php' method='post' >";
echo "<table border='1'>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['page_title'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='radio' name='test1' value='" . $row['id'] . "' /></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete' /> <input type='submit' name='edit' value='Edit' /></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";

mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do that with JavaScript:

```
<input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='
    this.form.action = "delete.php";
    this.form.submit();
' />
```

Or you can do it with PHP, by having the form action be, say, `action.php`, which would contain:

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['delete'])) {
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/delete.php';
else if (!empty($_REQUEST['edit'])) {
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/edit.php';
}
```

Comment: I've got your PHP way working, but I'm not convinced it is the better option than @ThiefMaster's (which I'm yet to get working). Can you please explain why you would use your approach ahead of the other.

Comment: Because if you separate logic inside files, it will be easier to manage. Next time you need to make changes to the edit functionality, you edit the `edit.php` file and you know exactly where to look. If you put your whole application in one file, the you will have to start hunting for where the logic could be. Separating logic into multiple files is a good idea for the project as a whole, not just for this part of it.

Answer (score 5):

Check for `isset($_POST['delete'])` and `isset($_POST['edit'])`.

However, it's a **bad** idea to have the *delete* button first. When pressing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, browsers usually use the first button - and pressing enter in a form should not delete stuff.

Comment: dont forget to change the action to point to the current page

Comment: I see where you're going with this, but where do I check for this?

Comment: at the top before you do this echoing

Comment: so `if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
 echo "<form name='wer' id='wer' action='delete.php' method='post' >";
}
if(isset($_POST['edit'])) {
 echo "<form name='wer' id='wer' action='edit.php' method='post' >";
}` ???